# How to export HTML table into excel using AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to export data into excel format. it exports into .xls format but when I'm open this file into google sheet it shows an HTML table.

The angularjs Code is

```
 function download(argument) 
{
  console.log(argument)
  var data_type = 'application/xls';
  vm.dateForMonth= argument;
    //console.log(  vm.dateForMonth);
    var table_div = document.getElementById('table_wrapper1');
    var table_html = table_div.outerHTML.replace(/ /g, '%20');

    var blob = new Blob(['\ufeff',table_div.outerHTML], {
        // type: "application/xls;charset=utf-8"
       // type: "application/vnd.ms-excel;charset=utf-8"
       type: "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet;charset=utf-8"
      });
    console.log(blob);
    if(argument!=null || argument != undefined)
    {
      saveAs(blob, "Time-Sheet_" + vm.dateForMonth+ ".xlsx");
    }
    else
    {
    /* var month=   moment(new Date()).format("MMM"); 
     console.log(month);
     */     
     saveAs(blob, "Time-Sheet_" + moment(new Date()).format("MMM YYYY") + ".xlsx");
   }

 }


}
```

Comment: I can help you with this. Can you create a demo code on https://plnkr.co/ and let me know . I'll make necessary modifications accordingly. Also its better to iterate over JSON which is creating the `table` rather than getting it from HTML code